# What are unzip2dir / unrar2dir

Tags: bash, compression

I [found some useful](https://gist.github.com/dotgc/62c527153da61e7e89a9) extract and compress functions for my `.bashrc`.

But I am struggling to get `unzip2dir` / `unrar2dir` to respond.

```
*.zip) unzip2dir $1 ;; 
*.rar) unrar2dir $1 ;;
```

(unrar2dir: command not found)

But I have no clue what this is or how to get it to work.

Comment: Welcome! I would say those are custom functions from the developer using `unzip` and `unrar`, he forgot to say. There's no packages (I'm on Mint) with those names.

Comment: The only instances of these command names that can be found by DuckDuckGo on the web are copy-pasted from each other. The `extract()` function that they are part of is also broken in all instances (can't handle files with spaces in their names). If the original author of this cargo cult piece of code had a utility or shell function that implemented these or not is not know.